# xcode not showing simulator schemes

Tags: ios, xcode

when i create a new project in xcode, i only see "iOS Device" under the list of possible run schemes. all simulators are missing. the strange thing is, if i do the exact same thing from a different user account, the resulting new project will show all schemes as expected.

i assume there is some kind of file permission problem with one of the user accounts, but i would like to know what the responsible files would be that could cause this. i already tried to repair disk permissions, no change.

i also removed xcode completely and re-installed, but no change.

many posts here suggest that a change of deployment target or settings verification can cure this, but in my case this did not help.

Comment: add screenshot please

Comment: When you check Preferences->Downloads, what simulators are listed?

Comment: How did you resolve this? I'm seeing the same thing with 6.3.1